# Using processing.runandload in QGIS 3

Tags: pyqgis, qgis-processing, hillshade, qgis-3

I want to create and elevation hillshade but I found the script for QGIS 2.18. What should I use instead of processing.runandload? Here is my script on QGIS 2.99 python console:

```
import processing
rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer("C:/Users/Mustafa Uçar/Desktop/Tutorial/qgis_data/dem/dem.asc", "hillshade")
rasterLyr.isValid()
processing.runandload("gdalogr:hillshade", rasterLyr, 1, False, False,1.0, 1.0, 315.0, 45.0, "C:/Users/Mustafa Uçar/Desktop/Tutorial/qgis_data/dem/hillshade.tif")
#to verify the output image
processing.runandload()
```

Comment: Can't confirm as I am not really using 2.99 but try replacing `runandload()` with `runAndLoadResults()`.

Comment: @Joseph I tried this bu it says TypeError: runAndLoadResults() takes from 2 to 4 positional arguments but 10 were given

Comment: I also get this error in another script: AttributeError: module 'processing' has no attribute 'RunAndLoadResults'

Answer (score 9, accepted):

I followed @Joseph directions and it helps me to see another visions. I opened processing toolbox in QGIS and complete missing parameters. Here is the last version:

```
import processing   
rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer("C:/qgis_data/dem/dem.asc", "Hillshade")
rasterLyr.isValid()

parameters = {'INPUT': rasterLyr, 
                'BAND': 1, 
                'COMPUTE_EDGES': False,
                'ZEVENBERGEN': False,
                'Z_FACTOR': 1.0,
                'SCALE': 1.0,
                'AZIMUTH': 315,
                'COMBINED': False,
                'ALTITUDE': 45,
                'MULTIDIRECTIONAL': False,
                'OUTPUT': "C:/qgis_data/dem/hillshade.tif"}

processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:hillshade',parameters)
```

Comment: Good catch! I think when I posted, I was using a slightly older version which probably explains why those parameters didn't show up for me. Glad you got it working though :)

Comment: I am happy to hear that :)

Comment: @MustafaUçar please accept the answer that solved your problem so this thread can be marked as solved

Answer (score 10):

I think with the new QGIS 3.0, it is much easier to incorporate the input parameters of an algorithm into a **dictionary** which can then be called using:

```
processing.runAndLoadResults()
```

which is the equivalent to the QGIS <= 2.18 version:

```
processing.runandload()
```

---

So your code could look like:

```
import processing
rasterLyr = QgsRasterLayer("C:/Users/Mustafa Uçar/Desktop/Tutorial/qgis_data/dem/dem.asc", "hillshade")
rasterLyr.isValid()

parameters = {'INPUT': rasterLyr, 
                'BAND': 1, 
                'COMPUTE_EDGES': False,
                'ZEVENBERGEN': False,
                'Z_FACTOR': 1.0,
                'SCALE': 1.0,
                'AZIMUTH': 315,
                'ALTITUDE': 45,
                'OUTPUT': "C:/Users/Mustafa Uçar/Desktop/Tutorial/qgis_data/dem/hillshade.tif"}

processing.runAndLoadResults('gdal:hillshade', parameters)
```

---

Note that `gdalogr:hillshade` is now currently `gdal:hillshade`.